# Does the equation $(AB-BA)^2=I_n$ have a solution for each $n\geq 3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Does the equation $(AB-BA)^2=I_n$ have a solution for each $n\geq 3$? $A$ and $B$ are matrices?

I found out that the equation $(AB-BA)^m=I_n$ does have solution when $n=km$ where $k$ is an arbitrary integer number. It should be noted that $m>1$ is an integer number. To prove, we just need to consider $C=\operatorname{diag}(r_1,..., r_m)$ where $r_1,..., r_m$ are the roots of $x^m-1=0$, i.e., the eigenvalues of matrix $C$. In this case we know $\operatorname{trace}(C)=0$, and so there are two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $C=AB-BA$, and also it is vivid that $C^m=I_m$. For each $n=km$, we can duplicate the matrix $C$, $k$ times to get an $mk\times mk$ matrix to consider as new matrix $C$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $$
U = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, 
V = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then 
$$
UV = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix},
VU = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
hence 
$$
UV - VU = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and its square is the identity.

To create a $2n \times 2n$ matrix with the same characteristic, let $A_n$ consist of $n$ copies of $U$ along the diagonal in blocks, and let $B_n$ be $n$ copies of $V$ along the diagonal in blocks. Then $$(A_n B_n - B_n A_n)^2 = I_{2n}.$$

This leaves open the question for matrices of odd size. Offhand, I'm guessing that there might be no solution in that case, but perhaps there's something similar to this one, where $AB - BA$ turns out to be rotation by $\pi$ about the axis $(1,1,1)$ or something.

**Post-comment remarks**
Will Jagy closes this out by noting that if $n$ is odd, and you have a solution consisting of matrices $A$ and $B$, then you can let
$$
W = AB - BA
$$
This can be put in Jordan normal form so that 
$$
P^{-1} W P
$$
is a Jordan-block matrix. And its square is the identity, because it's $P^{-1} W^2 P$, and $W^2$ is assumed to be $I$. The square of a jordan block is the identity only if the block itself is diagonal, hence $P^{-1}WP$ is diagonal.

Replacing $A$ and $B$ with $A' = P^{-1}AP$ and $B' = P^{-1} B P$, we have 
$$
A'B' - B'A' = P^{-1} W P
$$ 
is diagonal, and its square is still the identity. Hence all its diagonal entries are $\pm 1$, so its trace is $\pm 3$ or $\pm 1$. But in general, $tr(AB - BA) = 0$, so we have a contradiction.

Conclusion: for odd $n$, there are no such matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: $$
U = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, 
V = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$ also works

Comment: That percussive sound you just heard was me smacking my forehead so hard that locals thought there was an earthquake. :)

Comment: I think we can rule out odd $n;$ I think we can arrange that the Lie bracket is diagonal, in which case all diagonal entries are $\pm 1,$ so the trace is odd and nonzero. Not completely sure yet

Comment: Yeah, that should work; let the bracket by $W,$ put it in Jordan form as $P^{-1} W P.$ With square the identity, it is actually diagonal. Our revised matrices are $P^{-1} U P$ and $P^{-1} V P.$ I thought the loud sound was the movie, Lucy is on cable, Scarlett Johansson

Comment: Excellent. I was thinking of the SVD, but Jordan form is better. I'll add that to my answer to close this out.

Comment: It is notable that $A_n = I_n \otimes U$ and $B_n = I_n \otimes V$ where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.

Comment: Also, it is a notable (and well known, I believe) theorem that the matrices that can be written in the form $AB - BA$ are precisely those of trace $0$.

Comment: Sure, but I figured that rather than bringing in the K product, I could just describe it, since OP might not know about it. Note that I used the trace-zero thing one line from the end, without proof, because it's dead simple in coordinates. :)

Comment: Will Jagy's construction of $U$ and $V$ is not merely simpler, but also better because it works on all fields, including any field of characteristic 2.

Comment: I completely agree (and also liked your answer below:) ).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I am wondering if I replaced 2 by an arbitrary number like $m$, what would be the answer? I think for a prime number, say m, the equation will have solutions for any $n=km$. Am I right? And, can this be a if and only if? I mean that can I say "the equation will have a solution only in case that $n=km$ where $k$ is an arbitrary integer number.

Comment: Gosh...I don't know. You could just work through the proofs I gave and ask "at what stage did squaring matter?" The answer seems to be at the point near the end where I talk about the square of the diagonal matrix being the identity, so the entries are all $\pm 1$. What if the cube is the identity? Then the diagonal elements might be complex roots of unity, and things fall apart. In short: I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

This is Will Jagy's idea: Let $C = AB - BA$. If $C^2 = I$, then $(C - I)(C + I) = 0$. This implies $C$ is diagonalizable and its only eigenvalues are $\pm 1$. So we can pick a basis such that $C$ is diagonal. Now, for any matrices $A$ and $B$, we have $\text{tr}(AB - BA) = 0$, where $\text{tr}$ denotes the trace. But since $AB - BA = C$ is diagonal, the trace of $C$ is the sum of its eigenvalues. If all the eigenvalues are $\pm 1$, the multiplicity of $1$ must equal the multiplicity of $-1$, which is impossible if $n$ is odd.

To prove that $C$ is diagonalizable: One way to see this is to prove that any vector $\mathbf{v}$ can be written as $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}_{+} + \mathbf{v}_{-}$, where $\mathbf{v}_{+/-}$ are eigenvectors of $C$ with eigenvalues $\pm 1$, respectively. To do this, we can just set $\mathbf{v}_{+} = \frac{1}{2}(I - C)\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{-} = \frac{1}{2}(I + C)\mathbf{v}$. The identity $(C - I)(C + I) = 0$ implies that these are eigenvectors with the proper eigenvalues.

Comment: This works for powers other than squares.

Comment: To prove that $C$ is diagonalizable, it suffices to note that its minimal polynomial divides $x^2 - 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have dealt with the case of even $n$ nicely. Their disproofs for the existence of $A,B$ when $n$ is odd also work when the characteristic of the field is zero.

Since the OP does not specify the field, it is worth pointing out that $AB-BA=I$ is solvable if and only if $I$ is traceless. Therefore, when the field has characteristic $p>0$, $(AB-BA)^2=I$ could be solvable when $n$ is appropriate. E.g. if $n=p$ is an odd prime and the field is $GF(p)$, we have $AB-BA=I$ when
$$
A=\pmatrix{0\\ 1&0\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&1&0},
\quad B=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ &0&-2\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&0&1-p\\ &&&&0}.
$$